# Format-Table output from openfiles.exe

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to 'on the fly' format the output of openfiles.exe instead of saving the output to a CSV and importing it. 
If I simply run `openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo table` I get

```
ID       Accessed By          Type       Open File (Path\executable)
======== ==================== ========== =====================================
1558     AUSERNAME            Windows    D:\..\Imaging\Itool.ldb
```

Now I want to sort the results on the fly by either Accessed By or Open File so I have tried
`openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo table | Format-Table "Accessed By","Open File (Path\executable)" -auto`
Which just spits out the same thing as the first command. Ideally I only want "Accessed By" and "Open File (Path\executable)" and just be able to sort em by either one. I am trying to avoid doing the CSV thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky as `openfiles` isn't a PowerShell cmdlet. It just displays its data in a table but it's not objects it returns. PowerShell just takes them as strings.

```
$item = New-Object PSObject
switch -regex (openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo list) {
    '([^:]+):\s+(.*)$' {
        $item | Add-Member NoteProperty $Matches[1] $Matches[2]
    }
    '^$' {
        if ($item) { $item }
        $item = New-Object PSObject
    }
}
```

This uses the list format, parses it and constructs objects which you can then use. Wrap it in a function (or a subexpression with `$(...)`) and you can use `Format-Table`:

```
$(
    $item = New-Object PSObject
    switch -regex (openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo list) {
        '([^:]+):\s+(.*)$' {
            $item | Add-Member NoteProperty $Matches[1] $Matches[2]
        }
        '^$' {
            if ($item) { $item }
            $item = New-Object PSObject
        }
    }
) | ft 'Accessed By','Open File (Path\executable)' -auto
```

Or you just change the commands a little. I used `switch`'s intrinsic capability of iterating, but you can do the same with an explicit pipeline:

```
openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo list |
  ForEach-Object {
    $item = New-Object PSObject
  } {
    switch -regex ($_) {
      '([^:]+):\s+(.*)$' {
        $item | Add-Member NoteProperty $Matches[1] $Matches[2]
      }
      '^$' {
        if ($item) { $item }
        $item = New-Object PSObject
      }
    }
  }
```

Since this is a pipeline you can add more commands at the end at will.

Answer (score 2):

You can not format the output, because it returns array of strings. Instead you might try to parse it, although imho it's easier to save as csv and import

```
$out = openfiles /query /s SERVERNAME /fo table
$out | 
    Select-Object -Skip 2 | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        if ($_ -match '([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.*)') {
            New-Object PsObject -prop @{
                Id=[int]$matches[1]; 
                AccessedBy=$matches[2]
                Type=$matches[3]
                OpenFile=$matches[4]
            }
        }
    } | 
    Sort-Object OpenFile
```

(I have no chance to test openfiles)

Comment: For the regex I guess `\S` is easier to read than `[^\s]`. And you can test it by opening a file on `\\localhost\c$\...`; at least that's what I did to get more than a single row of data. User and file names may contain spaces, though, so the regex might match different things than you want (that's why I switched to list format which is a bit easier to parse).

Answer (score 2):

Having just done this you can easily convert the CSV output to a PowerShell object by doing the following

```
$FileList = Invoke-Expression "& C:\Windows\System32\openfiles.exe /query /s SERVERNAME /fo CSV" | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Select "Accessed By","Open File (Path\executable)"
```

Answer (score 0):

- "select-object -skip 8" (if you have the text as me when using openfiles.exe)